# PHP variable from HTML element? (NOT Input)

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm designing a website for a restaurant. You can make a reservation for how many people and at what time. For the people one, there's a `<span>` class that will have a number from 1 to 20 that the user can adjust.

I already know about the $_POST method for input fields and those are working just fine. However, I'm not a back-end developer my nature and thus don't know a whole lot about PHP. I can't seem to find a way to make a variable from the element with PHP.

With JavaScript it'd be as simple as $var = $("span"); or what have you. I'm not exactly sure how to do this with PHP.

To be clear, I want to make the contents of this span element into a variable for PHP. The $_POST method doesn't appear to work for non-input fields.

If anyone can help me out with this, that'd be great.

Comment: push the values of the span elements into an `<input type="hidden"/>` field. This can be either one hiddenfield for one `span` element or you push all values from all span elements comma separated into the hiddenfield.

Comment: The only way to send input to PHP is through `GET`, `POST`, and other four HTTP request methods. I would suggest the `GET` method by passing query strings like `.php?something=something`?

Comment: @Tyr This method worked for me. I used JavaScript to take the value of the span and assign it to a hidden input field. From there, the $_POST method worked. Seems like a bit of a roundabout way of doing it but it does work. Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery to parse the span content, why not use AJAX (p.e. $.post(url, data)) for the back-end requests?

Comment: @Narayon Because I don't know AJAX and would rather do something convoluted with a language I'm comfortable with than experiment with unpredictable code.

Comment: I understand and, since I don't have the specifications of the project, I agree. That said, give it a try on your spare time. Just search for $.post and $.get methods on the jQuery documentation to get you started. Async communication between client and server is a must-know pattern. Learning about it will make you a better developer.